# Move the data from one container to another container using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How to **move** the data from one container to another container in the same Azure storage account using Logic App?

In Azure, I have a storage account with two containers (test-1, and test-2). I want to move the files from one container to another container periodically.

Is there a way to achieve this process with a Logic App?

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to my logic app:

You ca use [List blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#list-blobs) first:

[image]

Then use [For each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop), within for each, you need to use [Get blob content using path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#get-blob-content-using-path) and [Create blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#create-blob).

[image]

=====================update=====================

Add a `Delete blob` action

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the detailed information @Frank. But It does the copy thing only. How to delete the files in the test-1 container once everything has been copied to the test-2 container.